# Docusign: how to list all the envelopes in the admin account

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to list all the envelopes present for my admin account but found no method in python SDK.

Please help me how can I list all the envelopes in the admin account

Comment: Hey Kshitij, are you just getting started with your integration? Are you using a developer sandbox account?

Comment: Yes.. I am using developer sandbox account..

Comment: answered below. If it helps, be sure to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Envelopes::listStatusChanges` method with from_date query parameter set. The response will contain an array of envelopes created from that date onward.

Here's an example:

```
def list_envelopes():
    """
    Lists the user's envelopes created in the last 10 days
    """

    #
    # Step 1. Prepare the options object
    #
    from_date = pendulum.now().subtract(days=10).to_iso8601_string()

    #
    # Step 2. Get and display the results
    # 

    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = base_path
    api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)

    envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
    results = envelope_api.list_status_changes(account_id, from_date = from_date)
    return results
```

You can find this sample and more in our [python QuickStarts repo.](https://github.com/docusign/qs-python)